# better way to detect lightbox clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to get my lightbox working in javascript.

Everything seems to work so far but its really messy, an seems really wrong how im looping to get the thumbails

just wanted to know what is the best way to do this?

```html
    <a href="#50279.jpg" class="thumbnail"><img src="thumbs/50279.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="50279.jpg"><img src="gallery/50279.jpg"></a>
    
    <a href="#D467_D3G6269R.jpg" class="thumbnail"><img src="thumbs/D467_D3G6269R.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="D467_D3G6269R.jpg"><img src="gallery/D467_D3G6269R.jpg"></a>
```

```html
        var gallery = document.getElementById("Gallery");
        var thumbnails = gallery.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail");
        var lightboxes = gallery.getElementsByClassName("lightbox");

        var items = gallery.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');

        function showLightBox(target, bool) {
            if (target) {
                if (bool) {
                    target.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    target.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

        function onClickLightBox(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.target.className == "lightbox") {
                showLightBox(event.target, false);
            }
        }

        function onClickThumbnails(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            showLightBox(items[event.currentTarget.myParam + 1], true);
        }


        for (var i = 0; i < lightboxes.length; i++) {
            lightboxes[i].addEventListener('click', onClickLightBox);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                if (items[i]) {
                    items[i].addEventListener('click', onClickThumbnails);
                    items[i].myParam = i;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean lightbox as [this](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) or some other library

Comment: There's a lot you can do to clear this up, because it's pretty hard to understand what's going on with some of this. The way you create and use the 'items' variable, for example, is way too messy. Why don't you give them a special class or something?